Weird API response with <script> JavaScript tag
I am working on a project in Python that scrapes a university portal website to retrieve a weekly schedule. I see from the developer tools that the schedule page makes a API call and receives a JSON response. The problems is that in that response contains a <script> tag with JavaScript code that calls a function on the data I want. I parsed the JSON to get only the values on the dictionary. Which is:
<script id="dados_semana" language="Javascript">
function getEventData() {
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var month = new Date().getMonth();
var day = new Date().getDate();
return {
 events: [
{
'id':1,
'start': new Date(2023,10,6,20,40),
'end': new Date(2023,10,6,22,30),
 'title': '<table><tr><td><label title=""></label><a title="Disciplina" href="../educacao/ver_edicoes_disciplina.aspx?id=59847">GESTA&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td><td>TP&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table>',
'body':'<table><tr><td><a title="Docente" href="../areapessoal/docente.aspx?codeuser=62688"><b>RUM</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><a href="../ver_horario/ver_horario.aspx?room=3727"><b>F409</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td COLSPAN="3"><a title="LEEC" href="../ver_horario/ver_horario.aspx?class=41413"><b>1NB</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></table>',
'footer':'<table><tr><td COLSPAN="2"><a href="../education/view_lesson.aspx?cd=744&cdt=11"> Sumários </a></td></tr></table>',
readOnly: true
},(...)]};}
</script>

I tried to get only the events return and turn it into a list of Dict for easy and rapid consultation, but it's been a nightmare because of the quotes and double quotes.
My thought process is to load all this into a html file but will be tiresome since I want to put the schedule into a database, and I would rather not use selenium or another JavaScript execution module.
Any suggestions or tips?

You're trying to execute JavaScript but only want to use a module that doesn't have the capability? I highly recommend Selenium.

I know selenium would help me alot with this. But I wanted to try to just obtain the values of the event without using it.

Why make it harder on yourself?

The learning, and make it more simple for future use

Simply put, Requests can not do what you want to do. You have to use a module that can run JavaScript. Selenium is the most supported. If you want something similar-ish to regulalr Requests, check out requests-html.

You can hack together something with regular expressions and stuff like that (yes, it might be a nightmare – power through), or use a JavaScript parser (no specific recommendations, and the best option might not be in Python – be prepared to use subprocess).
